# Concatenate data variables in Highchart Series

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to join multiple variables into the 1 series in highcharts so for I have this but it is not working:

```
series: [
                {
                 cursor: 'pointer',
                 name: 'IM',
                 data: responseJSON.resultset[0].IM0+','+responseJSON.resultset[1].IM1+','+responseJSON.resultset[2].IM2
               },
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that line:

```
data: responseJSON.resultset[0].IM0+','+responseJSON.resultset[1].IM1+','+responseJSON.resultset[2].IM2
```

Will create string. In Highcharts, you need to use array, so this is proper format:

```
data: [ responseJSON.resultset[0].IM0, responseJSON.resultset[1].IM1, responseJSON.resultset[2].IM2 ]
```

Note: IM0/1/2 need to be number/array of values/object of values.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out by myself later haha but forgot to post an edit

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the json object to data.

if you want all the values to be passed to json, json_encode all the values in a two dimensional array and then pass that as an object.

The example below shows how to do this.

var json=

```
$row1=array("america",125);
$row2=array("india",130);
$row3=array("australia",100);
$row4=array("africa",115);
$row5=array("japan",110);
$row6=array("china",108);
$row7=array();
array_push($row7,$row1);
array_push($row7,$row2);
array_push($row7,$row3);
array_push($row7,$row4);
array_push($row7,$row5);
array_push($row7,$row6);
echo json_encode($row7);?>;
```

series: [
                {
                 cursor: 'pointer',
                 name: 'IM',
                 data: json
               },